# let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be subspaces of $V$. then which of the following statements is Corrects?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space
$V$ and let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be subspaces of $V$. then which of the  following statements is  Corrects ?

$(a)$ $T(V_1\cap  V_2) = T(V_1) \cap  T(V_2).$

$(b)$ $T(V_1 \cup V_2) = T(V_1) \cup  T(V_2).$

My attempts : i know  that  intersection  two  subspaces  is  subspaces and union of two subspace  need not to be  subspaces

so  option $a)$  is   correct

option  $b)$  is  not  corrects

Is it  true ??

Comment: Have you tried to write down a standard double-inclusion argument, or perhaps a counterexample, in either case? That's where I'd start.

Comment: Try approaching the question via definition and element chasing.  Suppose that $x\in T(V_1\cap V_2)$.  Then there must be some $y\in V_1\cap V_2$ such that $T(y)=x$.  Does it follow then that $x\in T(V_1)$?  Does it also follow that $x\in T(V_2)$?  How about whether or not $x\in T(V_1)\cap T(V_2)$?  (*The element $y$ that I point out the existence of plays a critical role in these last few steps*).   Now... there is one more direction left for part (a) and two directions to do for part (b).  Can you continue?

Comment: Your remarks about intersection and union are correct, nevertheless, that does not completely verify nor refute the equalities. Even if you have established that both sides are subspaces, you still have to show them to be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is false. Take $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y)=(x+y,0)$. If$$V_1=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}\text{ and }V_2=\{(0,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\},$$then $T(V_1\cap V_2)=T(\{0\})=\{0\}$, whereas $T(V_1)\cap T(V_2)=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

(b) this holds for every funtion (linear or otherwise).

Comment: for  b)   if i  will take  ur counter  example  as  u have taken for option a)  then  it will not  True  ..can  elaborate  option   b)  more ...@Jose sir

Comment: @Messififa $T(V_1\cup V_2)=T(V_1)\cup T(V_2)=\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, in contrary  $$T(V_1 \cup V_2) = T(V_1) \cup  T(V_2)$$is the true choice. Note that $$ V_1 \cup V_2$$ does not have to be a subspace for the above statement to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong - the question didn't ask whether any of those sets were subspaces.

And your conclusions are both wrong as well. Another answer already shows that (a) is false. In fact (b) is true.

If $y\in T(V_1\cup V_2)$ then there exists $x\in V_1\cup V_2$ with $y=T(x)$. But $x\in V_1\cup V_2$ says $x\in V_1$ or $x\in V_2$; hence $y=T(x)$ is either in $T(V_1)$ or $T(V_2)$, so $y\in T(V_1)\cup T(V_2)$.

So $T(V_1\cup V_2)\subset T(V_1)\cup T(V_2)$. Conversely, $V_1\subset V_1\cup V_2$ shows that $T(V_1)\subset T(V_1\cup V_2)$. Similarly $T(V_2)\subset T(V_1\cup V_2)$, hence $T(V_1)\cup T(V_2)\subset T(V_1\cup V_2)$.